# Basic python, NxN matrix printing the terms being the sum of the term coordinates in the matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix

> Hy guys, i'm new to python, i'm trying to make an NxN matrix, that print out a matrix that have the terms value's being the sum of the coordinates of it.

> In this example i used N=5

```
    N = 5
    M = []
    linha = []
    for i in range (N):
      linha.append(0)
    for i in range(N):
      M.append(linha)
    print(f"{M}") # just to make sure it's printing the NxN matrix
    for i in range(N):
      for j in range(N):
        M[i][j] = i + j
    print(M) #returning the final matrix
```

> I'm getting this:

> [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8],

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

> While i was expecting:

> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],

> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],

> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

> Since, for example, the first term is the M[0][0], so 0+0=0

> Sorry if i wrote things that may be not too clear, but that's my problem, if anyone can help i would appreciate!

Comment: The code `for i in range(N): M.append(linha)` means that M[0], M[1] ...M[N] are all references to the **same** object `linha`.  So after that, when you change (for example) M[1][0], you're changing element 0 of the same object which all the rows of your matrix contain.

Comment: Thanks, i did'n know that i would somehow maintain the connection between the objetcs after appned.

Comment: Yet i want to make somehow a given N matrix, with this 'term sum coordinate' thing, if anyone can help with the code i appreciate!

Comment: You could set up the matrix by doing for example: `for i in range(N): M.append([0] * N)`

Comment: Or to simplify further, you could create your whole term-sum matrix in one line as: `M = [[i+j for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concise way of getting the desired result, using a nested list comprehension:

```
N = 5
M = [[i+j for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
print(M)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved the problem. Loved the way this is clean and concise!

Answer (score 0):

Like what was said in a comment:

> The code for i in range(N): M.append(linha) means that M[0], M[1] ...M[N] are all references to the same object linha. So after that, when you change (for example) M[1][0], you're changing element 0 of the same object which all the rows of your matrix contain.

This means you're always referencing the same variable. You could make a small change to your code, so the new list of zeroes is created independent of name using a list comprehension:

```
N = 5
M = []
for i in range(N):
    M.append([0 for i in range(N)])
print(f"{M}")

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        M[i][j] = i + j
print(M) #returning the final matrix
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i didn't knew i could add the loops inside the lists, solved the problem!